# Extracting runtime number of bits from integer

Tags: python

I need to extract some bits from an integer. However how many bits to be extracted is not fixed.

For example a certain code is generating 2 numbers `a` and `b`. What I want is a code that could do

```
c = a[b-1:0]
```

One of the methods I read about on the web is w say b is a fixed value 3, a simple method to do is

```
c=bin (a >> 0 & 0b111 )
```

But this could be done if value of b is fixed 3 i.e we right shift based on known fixed number of bits being anded i.e 3.

But what if the "3" is not fixed? During run time I may need lower 4 bits or 3 bits or 2 bits...anything.

I thing I tried and hoped it would work is

```
x = bin(a)
c= x[b-1:0]
```

But even this doesn't work.

Comment: `0b111` is just another way of representing `7`, which is `(2 ** 3) - 1`. Also note that `0 &` is pointless.

Comment: What bits exactly would you like `x[b-1:0]` to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your code is trying to access the bits of an integer using slice notation (`[:]`) but that only works with sequences, not integers.

First you need to decide if you want to work with a string representation of your number in binary, or an integer representation, and be consistent about that. Let's start with a string representation in binary. `a` is the input number, `b` is the number of bits.

```
>>> a = 35
>>> x = bin(a)
>>> x
'0b100011'
```

Now you want a string representation in binary of the integer that is the rightmost `b` positions of this string:

```
>>> b = 3
>>> x[-b:]
'011'
```

Deprived of its `0b` prefix, this string of 3 digits could mean anything. Some examples: in binary, 3; in decimal, 11; in octal 9; in hex, 17. *We* know from reading the code that it is part of the output from a `bin()` call, but the string doesn't carry that information around with it. The 3 digits mean whatever you intend them to mean.

If you want to convert that into something you can do arithmetic with, you call `int()` to convert it back to an integer. But because `int()` can't tell that the representation is supposed to be binary, do this:

```
>>> int(x[-b:],2)
3
```

The `2` passed as the second parameter to `int()` specifies what base the string is supposed to be in. It's not specifying a *conversion*: it's specifying an *interpretation*. It's optional, but if you leave it out then `int()` will use the default base, which is of course 10.

```
>>> int(x[-b:])
11
```

This happens because without any indication of the base, `011` means "eleven, with a leading zero". And `int()` converts a *string* to an *integer*: just *integer*, not *base-10 integer*. The internal representation of integer is only converted to base 10 when you ask the interpreter to display it. (Internally, Python integers actually use base 2**30, but most of us never have to think about that much, and I recommend you don't either.)

Now consider just working with integers. If the number of bits you want to mask off is `b` then (as johnrsharpe points out), you can get the corresponding mask using `(2**b - 1)`:

```
>>> 2**b - 1
7
```

Just to demonstrate this is what you actually want:

```
>>> bin(2**b - 1)
'0b111'
```

Then you can use the bitwise `&` operator to get the digits you want. This works sort of opposite to the string method: instead of chopping off the 3 digits that you want, you instead use `&` to set the digits you don't want to zero:

```
a = 100011
b = 000111 &
    ------
    000011
```

Then you can obtain the result directly without having to go through a string conversion and taking slices and converting back to integer:

```
>>> a & 2**b - 1
3
```

As you can see this gives the same result in one step. In your question I also see a right shift operator `>>` but because you are shifting zero positions it does nothing. If you also want to accept a shift quantity, say `s`, then in the examples above, use `(a >> s)` instead of `a`.

Comment: That indeed worked. One question about  the step : int(x[-b:],2),  I see that if i just write int(x[-b:]), i get a binary value and int(x[-b:],2) returns integer. What does adding 2 called as? I cant say it is converting the number to base 2 because it actually converting the base 2 to base 10.

Comment: @SachinBhutada I've edited the question and modified the example slightly to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it is not very clear what you actually want to do, but what I understood is that you want to extract 'b' last bits from 'a'.
 If two numbers are 'a' and 'b':
First, convert 'a' into binary:
`x = bin(a)[2:]`
Extracting last b bits from a:
`p = x[len(x)-b:]`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the (lower) **bits** of the integer value: something like this could do it:

```
def getbits(value, numbits):
    """ Extract the lower numbits of value. """
    return value & (2 ** numbits - 1)


value = 0b010011000111
for i in range(value.bit_length()+1):
    print('getbits({:012b}, {:2d}): {:12b}'.format(value, i, getbits(value, i)))
```

Output:

```
getbits(010011000111,  0):            0
getbits(010011000111,  1):            1
getbits(010011000111,  2):           11
getbits(010011000111,  3):          111
getbits(010011000111,  4):          111
getbits(010011000111,  5):          111
getbits(010011000111,  6):          111
getbits(010011000111,  7):      1000111
getbits(010011000111,  8):     11000111
getbits(010011000111,  9):     11000111
getbits(010011000111, 10):     11000111
getbits(010011000111, 11):  10011000111
```